# Windows 10: USB Audio device "cannot start (Code 10)"

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio

I just bought a [RadioShack Microphone Adapter 33-331](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/670215/Radio-Shack-33-331.html). It's a XLR to mini USB converter. Supposed to be plug-and-play, but sadly doesn't work.

The device gets recognized as an audio device, however, when checking the properties of the device in the "Devices and Printers" dialogue and then clicking on Hardware, I get "This device cannot start. (Code 10)" from one of the components:

[image]

Here are some steps I tried that you might try as well if you have a similar problem:

- [Scanned windows for corrupt system files and replaced them](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-sfc-scannow-to-repair-windows-system-files-2626161) by typing `sfc \scannow` into a terminal with admin privilegues

Comment: Although it can have other causes, the usual reason for "Code 10" is faulty hardware. Before asking you should have tested in another PC / different OS.

Comment: You think it's my computer? I'm trying Linux right now, hold on.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about the microphone itself... But please do the proper troubleshooting and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I just tried another machine, sadly didn't work either. :( Is there something else I could try? I literally just plugged it in for the first time some minutes ago...

Comment: Go back to the store and ask for a refund or replacement.